# android - styling checkbox and radiobutton

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to style my app and make own theme, but I faced with some problems, becouse I need some unusial behaviour.

I use Material Design theme with parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

## Overview

Views has colors:

- Text is `textColorPrimary`, `textColorSecondary`, `textColorTertiary`
- Button is unknown gray color
- Button text is `textColorPrimary` (?)
- Checkbox and radiobutton unchecked border is `textColorSecondary`
- Checkbox, radiobutton, sliders etc colors is `colorAccent`

But I need

- Buttons have `accentColor` background and white text
- All text (`textColorPrimary`, `textColorSecondary`, `textColorTertiary`) is a variants of dark green
- Checkbox, radiobuttons should be primary color when checked and unchecked too.

## My styles

### Button

So, I create style `Button.Default`

```
<style name="Button.Default" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and use It in my theme:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button.Default</item>
```

OK, color changed, but background didn't. I add this line to the theme style:

```
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorFakeAccent</item>
```

OK

### Checkbox

```
<style name="Checkbox.Default" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

And checkbox style didn't change. How can I set checkbox, radiobutton unchecked and checked color?

Comment: Thanks, It helps me. Can you post this as answer, to mark it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<item name="colorControlNormal"> <item name="colorControlActivated">` for change color of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write your styles in the `res/values-v21/styles.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

you can Add your own style and images like so

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/my_rbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/community_radiobutton_style" />
```

**custom_radio_button.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_off" />
</selector>
```

Comment: How custom_radio_button.xml is used?